# Print statement inside functioncall is not printing values Python

Tags: python, printing

When there is a print statement inside a function, it is not printing. 
I dont understand what is going wrong.

```
def test():
print("please print this")
return "return this"
```

And, my main function is like this:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
classwhereiwrotefunction.test()
```

When I use a debugger, and try to store the return value in a variable, it does show the value. But, does not print it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem is with indentation I guess. Try the below code it will work.

```
class Class_name:
    def test(self):
        print("please print this")
        return "return this"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    class_name = Class_name()
    print(class_name.test())

>> please print this
>> return this
```

Comment: Why is this marked as the answer? It doesnt even compile :S

Comment: i have posted it again below please go through the code

Comment: Delete your other answer -- I've updated this one (since its marked as the answer)